# What is the font in IE Title Bar?

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, titlebar

I just need to use the font which is being used by Microsoft in Internet Explorer Title bar and got the answer as ***"SEGOE"***. I dont knot know whether it is right.
   Does anybody know what is the **font used by Internet Explorer in its Title Bar** ?

Comment: If you don't trust the answer you got, why do you think you will trust any of our answers?

Comment: The font in the Title bar comes from OS, hence it varies depending on users choice, localization etc...